# magento xml for 1 cms page - js and css

Tags: javascript, css, xml, magento

I am trying to add an accordion to one CMS page in xml update.

I uploaded to 
default > default/js/ac/ and /css/ac/

and placed code in xml update pane like this:

```
<reference name="head"> <action method="addItem">
  <type>text/css</type>
  <name>css/ac/jquery-accordion.css</name>
  </action> <action method="addItem">
  <type>text/javascript</type>
  <name>js/ac/jquery-1.10.1.min.js</name>
  </action> <action method="addItem">
  <type>text/javascript</type>
  <name>js/ac/jquery-accordion.js</name>
  </action> </reference>
<reference name="header">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").jqueryAccordion();
    });
    </script>
</reference>
```

the dev of this code knows nothing about mangento. all he says is this:

1. Installation

Place the reference for CSS and Javascript files inside the “head” section of your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-accordion.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-accordion.js"></script>
```

2. HTML markup

jQuery Accordion is based in “DIV’s” and has a fluid layout. Take a look on this accordion composed by a two items:

```
<div id="accordion" class="accordion">

  <div class="accordion-item">

        <div class="accordion-header">

              <span class="title">Header</span>

        </div>

        <div class="accordion-content">

        </div>

  </div>

  <div class="accordion-item">

        <div class="accordion-header">

              <span class="title">Header</span>

        </div>

        <div class="accordion-content">

        </div>

  </div>
```

3. Put the fallowing code inside the head section of your page:

   ```
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {

           $("#accordion").jqueryAccordion();

     });
   ```

---

UPDATE: Now it is working but any ideas as to why Font-Awesome icons are skewed? – http://obscurelytitled.com/m1.9.1.1/jq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your hint **default > default/js/ac/ and /css/ac/** just try this.,

```
<reference name="head">
      <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ac/jquery-1.10.1.min.js</name></action>
      <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ac/jquery-accordion.js</name></action>
      <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/ac/jquery-accordion.css</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="header">
       <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(document).ready(function() {
              $("#accordion").jqueryAccordion();
          });
       </script>
    </reference>
```